# How to send push notifications from server to app using Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to send push notifications from server to app using Firebase, but when the notification reaches app, my app is crashing.

PHP code:

```
       <?php

       $registrationIds = array("USER-DEVICE-TOKEN" );

       $message = array
       (
        'message'   => 'My awesome message',
        'title'     => 'My awesome title',
        'subtitle'  => 'My awesome subtitle',
        'tickerText'    => 'My awesome Ticker text',
        'vibrate'   => 1,
        'sound'     => 1,
        'largeIcon' => 'large_icon',
        'smallIcon' => 'small_icon'
       );


       $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
       $fields = array(
         'registration_ids' => $registrationIds,
         'data' => $message
        );
       $headers = array(
        'Authorization:key = GOOGLE-API-KEY',
        'Content-Type: application/json'
        );
       $ch = curl_init();
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
       curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);  
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
       $result = curl_exec($ch);           
       if ($result === FALSE) {
           die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
       }
       curl_close($ch);

       echo $result;
```

[Output of PHP Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjiom.png)

My Firebase messaging service:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    //Displaying data in log
    //It is optional
    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
    Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody()); // LINE 24
    //Calling method to generate notification
    sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody(),remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle());
}

//This method is only generating push notification
//It is same as we did in earlier posts
private void sendNotification(String messageBody,String messageTitle) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.mainlogo)
            .setContentTitle(messageTitle)
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
}
       }
```

[Crashing error when push notification comes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJHeJ.png)

Hope for your help

Comment: NPE in line 24 of file `MyFirebaseMessagingService`. The error is quite descriptive. Put a breakpoint there and check what is happening.

Comment: You actually have Good English there isn't anything wrong

Comment: @bigdestroyer ready, i've marked line with comment "// LINE 24"

Comment: Seems that `remoteMessage.getNotification()` is returning null. Try with `get.Data` instead. Actually you are sending a data push message, not a notification one.

Comment: @bigdestroyer , thank you for help.

Comment: Read this blog post for more complete guide. http://developine.com/firebase-cloud-messaging-push-notification-android-tutorial/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if `remoteMessage.getNotification()` is not NULL. I think it is NULL because you are not sending the param 'notification' in your `$fields` array of your PHP code. You are sending 'data'. So, when you send the parameter 'data' you have to get that parameter with `remoteMessage.getData()`.

Try to print the content of `remoteMessage.getData().toString()` in your onMessageReceived method. It should print the data you are sending in the notification.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for help, i've changed "data" to "notification" in my php array, and it works!

Comment: @YuraRosiak I've written same code but its not working. can you hlp plz?

Comment: @TashenJazbi could you please provide details on the error you are getting?. I mean, Do you receive the notification in the system tray? Do you get the onMessageReceived called?. Are you getting any exception?

Comment: onMessageReceived not being called :( . I've asked question there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39870556/onmessagereceived-never-called-in-notification-from-server-using-firebase-in-and/39872412#39872412

Comment: read this blogpost http://developine.com/how-to-send-firebase-push-notifications-from-app-server-tutorial/