# onMessageReceived never called in notification from server using Firebase in Android

Tags: php, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm sending notification from server using Firebase in Android. My code works when I send a notification from Firebase Console, but it doesn't work when I send a message from my server. I turned on debugging and I analyzed that `onMessageReceived` method of FirebaseMessagingService is never called.

Here is my FirebaseMessagingService code:

```
public class FirebaseMessagingService extends com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService {
    private static final String TAG = FirebaseMessagingService.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        showNotification(remoteMessage.getData().get("message"));
    }

     private void showNotification(String message){

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle("Firebase Push Notification")
                    .setContentText(message)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
        }
    }
```

Here is my PHP code of server side"

```
public function sendPushNotificationToGCMSever($token, $message){

        //include_once 'config.php';

        $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';

        $fields = array(
                'registration_ids' => $token,
                'notification' =>  $message
        );

        $headers = array(
                'Authorization:key=' . SERVER_KEY,
                'Content-Type:application/json'
        );
        $ch = curl_init();

        $ch = curl_init();
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
       curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);  
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        curl_close($ch);

        return $result;
    }
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you :)

Comment: Is your app in foreground or in background state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message) says that (to send a notification like the console does) your `$fields` should be (if `$message` is a string)

```
$fields = array(
                'to' => $token,
                'notification' =>  array(
                       'body' => $message
                ),
        );
```

You can also choose the icon for the notification by setting `'icon' => 'the name of some file in res/drawables'` as described [in this blog post](http://codingaffairs.blogspot.dk/2016/06/firebase-cloud-messaging-push.html)

Also see the difference between data only messages and notifications in the guide.

If you try data only messages and `onMessageReceived`, then you possibly forgot to add (as mentioned in the [guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client))

```
<service
    android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
AndroidManifest.xml
```

Comment: This would send a data message, while the console will always send notification messages. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages

Comment: I've tried the same as you've written but no luck :(